# Can purchase order lines be imported with DIXF without a header?

Tags: axapta, data-import, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

While importing purchlines using the data import export framework with a purchase id that does not exist, will the Standard AX create a purchase header or throw an error stating that purchase id does not exist?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to do same basic research on your own before asking a question. It only takes a few minutes to test what you are asking.

Comment: Same question in AX community: [importing purchLine with an non-existing purchid](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/198361)

Answer (score 1):

The Data Import/Export Framework entity for purchase order lines will create a purchase order header if a `PurchId` is provided in the staging data (see method `GeneratePurchTableLink` in class `DMFPurchLineEntityClass`). It should not be possible to not provide a `PurchId` since that field is mandatory in the staging table.

Please take care to also provide a valid `VendAccount`, otherwise the created purchase order will be incorrect.